# Custom order of items displayed in ModelChoiceField

Tags: python, django, database, sorting

I already had a look in older questions but didn't find an answer that could solve my problem.

Ok, let's assume that I have a model called 'Project':

```
class Project(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  parentproject = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name="parentproject_related", blank=True, null=True,
                                  verbose_name="parent project")

  ... a lot more ...
```

So with this model I can create projects and sub-projects. A project can have several sub-projects which can be identified by the `parentproject` field.

Inside the `DB` all projects are inside one table:

```
project1
project2
subproject1
subprojectA
project3
subprojectB
subproject2
```

With the help of two for-loops an can create the real view onto the data model:

```
project1
  subproject1
  subproject2

project2
  subprojectA
  subprojectB

project3
```

Now I want that this sorted list is display inside a ChoiceField, so the user can select the appropriate project. Is there a simple way to achieve this? It would also be nice to indent the names of the subprojects for better readability.

Thanks so far!

Answer (score 2):

I've used mptt heavily and I agree that if you don't need multiple levels of depth then it's best to avoid it as it does bring some limitations and potential issues with tree corruptions.

Here's how I've solved this in the past inspired by mptt's tree field:

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

from .fields import ProjectChoiceField
from .models import Project


    class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):

        parentproject = ProjectChoiceField(
            queryset=Project.objects.all(), required=False)

        class Meta:
            fields = ['name', 'parentproject']
            model = Project
```

**fields.py**

```
import itertools
from collections import OrderedDict

from django import forms
from django.forms.fields import ChoiceField
from django.forms.models import ModelChoiceIterator
from django.utils.encoding import smart_text
from django.utils.html import conditional_escape
from django.utils.text import mark_safe


class NestedModelChoiceIterator(ModelChoiceIterator):

    def __iter__(self):
        if self.field.empty_label is not None:
            yield ("", self.field.empty_label)

        for obj in self.get_linear_tree(self.queryset):
            yield self.choice(obj)

    def get_linear_tree(self, queryset):
        # We use ordered dict because otherwise the queryset ordering goes kaput.
        project_tree = OrderedDict()

        for project in queryset.select_related('parentproject'):
            parent_project_id = project.parentproject_id

            if parent_project_id:
                project_tree.setdefault(parent_project_id, []).append(project)
            else:
                project_tree.setdefault(project.pk, []).append(project)

        flattened_tree = itertools.chain(*project_tree.itervalues())
        return list(flattened_tree)


class ProjectChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):

    def __init__(self, queryset, *args, **kwargs):
        # you can make this into a mixin for more flexibility
        self.level_indicator = kwargs.pop('level_indicator', '---')
        super(ProjectChoiceField, self).__init__(queryset, *args, **kwargs)

    def _get_level_indicator(self, obj):
        # If you plan to have multiple levels
        # then you'll need to go up the tree here.
        if obj.parentproject_id:
            level = 2
        else:
            level = 1
        return mark_safe(conditional_escape(self.level_indicator) * level)

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        """
        Creates labels which represent the tree level of each node when
        generating option labels.
        """
        level_indicator = self._get_level_indicator(obj)
        return mark_safe(level_indicator + ' ' + conditional_escape(smart_text(obj)))

    def _get_choices(self):
        # If self._choices is set, then somebody must have manually set
        # the property self.choices. In this case, just return self._choices.
        if hasattr(self, '_choices'):
            return self._choices

        # Otherwise, execute the QuerySet in self.queryset to determine the
        # choices dynamically. Return a fresh ModelChoiceIterator that has not been
        # consumed. Note that we're instantiating a new ModelChoiceIterator *each*
        # time _get_choices() is called (and, thus, each time self.choices is
        # accessed) so that we can ensure the QuerySet has not been consumed. This
        # construct might look complicated but it allows for lazy evaluation of
        # the queryset.
        return NestedModelChoiceIterator(self)

    choices = property(_get_choices, ChoiceField._set_choices)
```

How it looks in the admin:

[image: admin]

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt) project to help you. It supports tree structure so you can create projects and sub-project relationship very easily. You can also get subtree in one sql query without traversing the tree.

Here's their official example on how to create parent relationship: http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/tutorial.html#set-up-your-model

Comment: thanks, I'll have an eye on that. But maybe there is another solution for my problem instead of including another package...

Comment: Good luck with that. But I still think that django-mptt is easy enough to support what you need by simply calling `object.get_children().order_by('foo')`(versus your implementation with for loops). Including mature packages in your project only help you solve your problem not a burden.